# What does 'a reduction is tight' mean rigorously?

Tags: security-definition, reduction

As far as I know, when someone says 'a reduction is tight', it means that given that there is  an adversary $A$ with advantage $\epsilon$ and running time $t$ and another adversary $B$ utilizing $A$ to solve a problem $P$, the advantage and running time of $B$ are apporximated to those of $A$.

But here is my question:

When do we say $\epsilon ' \approx \epsilon$ and $t'  \approx t$ exactly? Is there any specific criterion? (e.g. $\epsilon' \approx \epsilon \Leftrightarrow |\epsilon ' - \epsilon| \leq negl$, or something else).

I cannot find rigorous mathematical definitions about reduction tightness.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to measure the tightness of a reduction (e.g., see [CMS]) is via the *tightness gap*, defined as $$\frac{t'}{\epsilon'}\big/\frac{t}{\epsilon}=\frac{t'\epsilon}{t\epsilon'}.$$
A reduction is then said to be tight if the tightness gap is $O(1)$ (ideally a small explicit constant).$^*$

However, as @Mark points out in the comments, [MW] argues that the above may not be the right measure when it comes to reductions involving decision problems/primitives (you can read more about why in the paper).

$^*$However, small polynomials are also considered tolerable.

[CMS]: Chatterjee, Menezes and Sarkar, *[Another Look at Tightness](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/442)*, SAC 2011.

[MW]: Micciancio and Walter, *[On the Bit Security of Cryptographic Primitives](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/077)*, EC 2018

Comment: Note that if you define the bit security of a (search) problem as $\kappa = \log_2 \frac{t}{\epsilon}$, this condition is simply that the bit securities $\kappa' - \kappa$ are close (within a constant factor). I mention the bit security formulation as the quantity $\frac{t}{\epsilon}$ is arguably the incorrect quantity to investigate for decision problems/primitives, see [on the bit security of cryptographic primitives](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/077) for details.

Comment: Fair point, would you like to write up an answer? I'll delete this one.

Comment: no your answer is good --- I don't know if what I've suggested can be found in the literature (this notion of tightness is not found in the paper I linked), and this question is asking for a reference request. Still, it might be a good pointer to complement your reference.

Comment: The notion you suggested is quite natural. (Amended the answer.)

Comment: Maybe these papers be useful:[ [Hofheinz-Jia-Pan-Asiacrypt2018](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/834)], [ [Langrehr-Pan-PKC2020](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/146)] which they also emphasize on considering **multi-challenge security definition rather than single challenge** when dealing with tight security reductions.